# How to go to new line in iTerm2 without executing command?

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm

Don't flag this as duplicate to answers that say append `\` because I am not asking for line continuation.

I want something equivalent to <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>  from default terminal in ITerm2. I want to treat line as a comment.

Just want to go to a new line without executing. And I don't want to erase the command as well.

```
$ hello world
$ previous line was not executed and its still there without showing errors
$ ls -la
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you want to treat a line as a comment, you can simply prepend `#`. I do this all the time. With `bash`, after you've written the command you don't want to execute, press `Control-A` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, type `#` and then press Enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iTerm, but rather the shell that you're using and whether or not the option `interactive_comments` is enabled or not.  To treat the line as a comment, you have to start the line with a comment character.

Bash Reference Manual ([Chapter 3.1.3) - Comments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Comments)

> In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which the interactive_comments option to the shopt builtin is enabled (see The Shopt Builtin), a word beginning with ‘#’ causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored. An interactive shell without the interactive_comments option enabled does not allow comments. The interactive_comments option is on by default in interactive shells.

```
$ shopt -s interactive_comments          <-------- Enable interactive_comments
$ shopt -u interactive_comments          <-------- Disable
```

To make this permanent, put the command in your `~/bash_profile` or `~/bashrc`.  It's enabled by default in Bash

Zsh Reference Manual ([Chapter 6.7) - Comments](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Comments)

> In non-interactive shells, or in interactive shells with the INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS option set, a word beginning with the third character of the histchars parameter (‘#’ by default) causes that word and all the following characters up to a newline to be ignored

```
% setopt interactive_comments         <------ Enable interactive_comments
% unsetopt interactive_comments       <------ Disable
```

To make the setting permanent, place the appropriate command in  your `~/.zshrc`.  It's disabled by default in Zsh.

Answer (score 2):

All <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> does is sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to the shell running in the current Terminal tab/window.

[image]

So you can get the same effect in iTerm2 by just typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]